# Linux host -a (all) command returns Host not found: 4(NOTIMP)

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking

For some reason, the Linux `host` command with the `-a` ("all") option, returns a "*not found: 4(NOTIMP)*" on two local machines. One is Ubuntu on WSL and another an Ubuntu server on a virtual machine. The host is a Windows 10 machine.

This is what I read on `man host`:

> -a     The -a ("all") option is normally equivalent to -v -t ANY. It also affects the behavior of the -l list zone option.

Now see the output I get on my local Ubuntu server:

```bash
$ host example.com
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
example.com mail is handled by 0 .
```

However:

```bash
$ host -a example.com
Trying "example.com"
Host example.com not found: 4(NOTIMP)
Received 29 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 135 ms
```

The above result is similar on WSL, and for any other domain I've tried. I ran the exact same command on a cloud server, and it produces an `ANSWER SECTION` with many lines, so this is clearly something in my setup. Not a big deal, but I'd appreciate pointers on how to troubleshoot and potentially fix it.

Comment: Don't use `-a`/`ANY`, it is useless. It never meant "all" and is explicitly deprecated now. See RFC 8482.

Comment: It still appears on the `man` page, it's still supported by some DNS servers, including Google's 8.8.8.8, and I still find it useful :). Thanks for the RFC reference, they make good security points that might help explain why some DNS servers don't implement it.

Comment: The problem you seem to forget is that "ANY" does NOT mean "ALL" contrrary to what everyone thinks. So it is *useless*. It *never* guarantees you to get all records, you get only the subset of records cached in the nameserver you query. Hence you shouldn't use it because it will be misleading. It will always appear everywhere because it is in the core DNS specifications written 40 years ago and noone will write an addendum to remove it. Yet, as the RFC says, it is deprecated.

Comment: I searched for the words "obsolete" and "deprecated" in the [RFC8482](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8482) but couldn't find any matches... anyway, I see what you mean now. Yes, it doesn't return all the results. Excellent point!

Comment: Glad you finally hit the important point (ANY != ALL) but you maybe still miss other things, like ANY being abused for malicious traffic and amplification attacks. You may want to read around what happened to produce this RFC (and how it is the result of some compromise among different parties), and those resources may help: https://blog.cloudflare.com/deprecating-dns-any-meta-query-type/ and https://blog.cloudflare.com/what-happened-next-the-deprecation-of-any/ and finally https://blog.cloudflare.com/rfc8482-saying-goodbye-to-any/;as explained in latest, some resolver reply now with NOTIMPL

Comment: And if you want to split hairs, the RFC starts with "The operator of an authoritative DNS server might choose not to
   respond to such queries for reasons of local policy, motivated by
   security, performance, or other reasons." A service not responding to a specific query seems to me a clear definition that the query type became deprecated and obsolete. The aim of the RFC is just to give **guidance** on how to signal this deprecation in order not to create more problems. The intent of deprecation is however pretty clear. Especially since it was never useful from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1316489/668905) that pointed me to the issue: *it's the DNS server that does not implement this option*.

See examples below, where the server is specified.

```
$ host -a example.com 208.67.222.222
Trying "example.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 208.67.222.222
Address: 208.67.222.222#53
Aliases:

Host example.com not found: 4(NOTIMP)
Received 29 bytes from 208.67.222.222#53 in 0 ms
```

But this works:

```bash
$ host -a example.com 9.9.9.9
Trying "example.com"
Trying "example.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 9.9.9.9
Address: 9.9.9.9#53
Aliases:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36095
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            38584   IN      NS      a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.            38584   IN      NS      b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.            38584   IN      RRSIG   NS 8 2 86400 20221007214840 20220916103018 1686 example.com. G7YjAGiKrLxOw0+Vr/qWj4y6ZGX9LEEQebcdPgUjW+QYErfT2rZwYUAx y/UC1ekIprbs2Qr4N/f6jWobpxGGmd8maJN1Bihyw7FS6oYUTMM2O2Vb gf5bAUJMin2BFyWhKs1YFkSFF+dmuxOtnqpWgg8HD7f9zL5o3hOjblsP Jt0=

Received 248 bytes from 9.9.9.9#53 in 10 ms
```

The network in question is configured to use a DNS server that does not support this option. The `NOTIMP` (Not Implemented) is the clue. Specifying an alternative DNS server with the `host` (or `dig`) command, or configuring a different default DNS resolver (which I haven't tried yet) are ways to get around it. Any other troubleshooting tips are still welcome.

**Update**: Based on comments on the question, it's worth noting that using `-a` (ANY) is not recommended since it does not actually fetch all results. See [RFC 8482](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8482) and a related blog post from Cloudflare (who owns 1.1.1.1 that doesn't support it): [Saying goodbye to ANY](https://blog.cloudflare.com/rfc8482-saying-goodbye-to-any/).